# Using prometheus with volume to store data

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-operator

We are using prometheus-operator with the for several month which working great.
Now we need to add persistent volume to save the data for 3 month and we use the following.

https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack

I've added the following: (we have gp2 storage class)

```
storageSpec:
  volumeClaimTemplate:
    spec:
      storageClassName: gp2
      accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 50Gi
```

https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/values.yaml#L1969

And I got error:

```
persistentvolumeclaim "prometheus-po-kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus-db-prometheus-po-kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus-0" not found,
```

should I add something in addition to the values.yaml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing components reference, you have to specify for which component you define storage - `prometheus.prometheusSpec`

Try this:

```
prometheus:
  prometheusSpec:
    storageSpec:
      volumeClaimTemplate:
        spec:
          accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
          resources:
            requests:
              storage: 50Gi
          storageClassName: gp2
```

You can find more in [values.yaml](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/values.yaml#L1969)

Comment: No, the chart is ok, you just have to set up your storageSpec for a proper component of Prometheus stack, check the link in the answer.

Comment: isnt what im doing alreay, I put it here https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/prometheus-operator/values.yaml#L1846 , what is the diffrance ?

Comment: If so, you should migrate to a new chart, because the old one is no longer supported and the repository is deprecated.

Comment: I've tried it also with the new chart (its actually the same for this config...) , did you try it? does it work for you ? https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/values.yaml#L1969

Comment: should I do something in additon to this config ?

Comment: What do you mean? Just take default values from the new chart and configure them to meet your needs.

Comment: Ok thanks, how I can insure that the data is saved in the volume, how can I verfiy this?

Comment: You can find your pvc with `kubectl get pvc` and then `kubectl describe pvc`, if promtheus pod mounted the pvc you should be ok.
You could also just `exec` into pod and `touch` a file and then restart pod, if after a restart file exists you are fine.